# PHP Find and replace after in a string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have some strings which contain the words `LIMIT 3, 199` or `LIMIT 0, 100`.

Basically I want to replace the word LIMIT and everything after it in my string.

How do I do this in PHP? str_replace only replaces an item and the LIMIT text after is dynamic/

So it could be

```
WHEN JOHN WAS TRYING HIS SQL QUERY, HE FOUND THAT LIMIT, 121
// RETURN WOULD BE
WHEN JOHN WAS TRYING HIS SQL QUERY, HE FOUND THAT

WHEN JOHN TRIED LIMIT 343, 333 HE FOUND
// RETURN WOULD BE
WHEN JOHN TRIED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace out `LIMIT.+$` using `preg_replace` with pattern `/LIMIT.+$/m`

That is to say:

```
$string = preg_replace("/LIMIT.+$/m","",$string);
```

Comment: Happy with all answers. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `strpos` to find the position of `LIMIT` within the string, and then use `substr` to return the string up until that point.  Really pretty basic string manipulation.

Or perhaps use `preg_replace` if you want a one-liner, though I don't think going to the regex toolchest is needed here.

Comment: That's still a one liner :) `substr($string,0,strpos($string,"LIMIT"));`

Comment: But that only works if he has `LIMIT etc.` in his string once.

Comment: @Asad that is correct, but the requirement was to remove everything after an occurrence of `LIMIT`, so if it is in there two or more times, the multiple occurrences would be removed when removing everything after the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [`stristr`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) (case insensitive). Will work only for versions `>= php 5.3.0`

```
$str = strstr($your_string, 'LIMIT', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recommend against using regexes when you don't understand them, here's a simple answer that doesn't use them (do note, I do recommend learning regexes, but they aren't easy to learn):

```
$output = substr($input, 0, strpos($input, 'LIMIT'))
```

Comment: This deletes everything BUT the LIMIT etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strstr`

```
$break = "LIMIT";
$array = array();
$array[] = "WHEN JOHN WAS TRYING HIS SQL QUERY, HE FOUND THAT LIMIT, 121";
$array[] = "WHEN JOHN TRIED LIMIT 343, 333 HE FOUND";

echo "<pre>";
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    echo strstr($value, $break, true), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
WHEN JOHN WAS TRYING HIS SQL QUERY, HE FOUND THAT 
WHEN JOHN TRIED
```